# Regex not working for IE11 but working on chrome/firefox

Tags: jquery, regex, internet-explorer-11

I know this has been discussed a lot but couldn`t find good solution that would work for me. I have tried many things but something just doesnt work on ie11. This was tested and was working on chrome and firefox.

```
var myTitle = $('select[name="parameters[title]"] :selected').text();
var myMatchForRegex = $('select[name="parameters[my_list][]"] option');
var regex = new RegExp('^' + myTitle + '[-]{1}.+$', 'gm');
console.log("my regex test: " + regex);

myMatchForRegex.each(function (index, item) {
    if (!item.text.match(regex)) {
         item.hide();
    } else {
         item.show();
    }
})
```

Maybe someone can help me and show me where is my mistake why it does not work in ie11?

P.S. If this changes something - myMatchForRegex is an object which contains X amount of select items and items gets updated (show/hide) based on which "myTitle" has been selected before, that is why I use each there.

Comment: Note that your pattern can be simplified to: `new RegExp('^' + myTitle + '[-].+$', 'gm')`

Comment: Don't use the `g` modifier when just using a regexp for testing. It's only needed when you need to get or replace all the matches.

Comment: You can't hide `<option>` cross browser. Won't work in Safari either. Choices are remove/replace or disable/enable

Comment: Try to set debugger and use F12 developer tools to check your code on IE browser, whether it contains some error. Besides,  can you post the Enough code (include the select options values) to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).